# c++ call thread constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was reading concurrency in action and came up with this piece of code. However, i dont quite understand why line<1> is syntax valid. Also, how the order got determined? is it possible to put `std::thread t(&my_x, &X::do_lengthy_work);` instead? how many inputs can take based on the code over here?

```
class X
{
public:
void do_lengthy_work();
};

X my_x;
std::thread t(&X::do_lengthy_work,&my_x);  //<1>   the bood says This code will invoke my_x.do_lengthy_work() on the new thread, because the address of my_x is supplied as the object pointer
```

Comment: Try `std::thread t(X::do_lengthy_work,&my_x);` instead.

Comment: @Havenard im new to c++ multithreaded. lots of new concepts to me. btw, just one off topic question, what IDE r u using? mine is vs2010, which doesnt support thread lib. i was thinking to switch to other ide.

Comment: @Havenard  No, the & is necessary when dealing with member functions.  It's because of the std::bind() logic.

Comment: @STNYU It's because `std::thread` is only available in C++11. Only Visual Studio 2013 starts supporting this.

Comment: @Christophe what bind logic? do u have a link for this topic?

Comment: @Havenard correct. i know

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/  bind allows you to do define function objects and bind parameters to them.  And it shares the calling convetion with the thread constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are confused by the syntax here.

This is just a constructor call for an object of type [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) named `t` (so the arguments order did not "get determined", it is *defined* by the constructor signature).

Two parameters are expected by this constructor :

**1) A callable** : `&X::do_lengthy_work` , as a pointer to a member function, is a Callable.

**2) The arguments** expected by the Callable : a member function always has an implicit `this` argument of type `(const) X*` : this is why here you pass `&my_x`, the address of the object on which the Callable will be called.

If you add an argument to `do_lengthy_work`, then you need to specify it when you construct the thread as well :

```
class X
{
public:
   void do_lengthy_work(int i) {}
};

int main() {
   X my_x;
   std::thread t(&X::do_lengthy_work,&my_x, 2);
                                          ^^^^
}
```

Comment: thanks for the elaboration of the syntax. i did get confused by the rules.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent book about the topic !

`std::thread t(...);` creates a thread object t.  The first argument of the constructor must be either the adress of a function, or an executable class (i.e. a class with operator() defined).

For ordinary functions like `void f(){... }`, it would be sufficient to give its name as first argument  `f`.  For member function, you have to give its full name, so here:  `X::do_lengthy work`.  But for getting the pointer to the mbmer function an explicit `&` is required (see C++11 standard, section 5.3.1, pt 4).

The arguments following the first arguments will be given to the function when the thread starts and wants to execute it.  In the specific case of member functions, the very first argument will be used to say on which object the function has to be executed.

So roughly speaking `thread(&class::member_function, arg1, arg2, ... arg n)` will call `arg1.member_function (arg2, .... arg n)`.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, how the order got determined? is it possible to put std::thread
>   t(&my_x, &X::do_lengthy_work); instead?

As with any other c++ function order determined by function signature, in this case `std::thread` constructor signature:

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

from [std::thread documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

As you can see that `Function` is the first parameter and parameters follow (if any). So you cannot put pointer to class before pointer to method.